# Ext.util.Format.number - how do I preserve decimal places when adding thousand separator?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've got a bunch of numbers in different units of measure requiring different decimal precision. They all are rendered in the same component. In this component - I need to format numbers to include a thousand separator.

This is how I'm currently doing it

```
Ext.util.Format.number(floatValue.toFixed(this.euStore.getById(euId).get('DecimalPrecision')), '0,000.00');
```

Where `this.euStore.getById(euId).get('DecimalPrecision')` returns anywhere from 0 - 4.

I need to preserve these decimal places when `Ext.util.Format.number` is called to add in the thousand seperator, because it always gets 2 decimal places using the current format, `'0,000.00'`

Is there a way to do this with the built in number formatter or do I need to write my own function? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up figuring it out shortly after posting. I saved the decimal precision in a var

`var decimalPrecision = this.euStore.getById(euId).get('DecimalPrecision')`

and then built the format string using `Ext.String.repeat` to repeat the decimal places based on the precision value.

`var format = '0,000.' + Ext.String.repeat('0', decimalPrecision);`

then passed that to

`Ext.util.Format.number(myNumber, format)`

to get the result I needed. Thanks for your suggestions!